# Lets encrypt, "Your connection is not secure"

Tags: ssl, dns, lets-encrypt

I´ve tried to add a SSL-Certificate to my webpage with Lets Encrypt as verifier. After I followed the steps described at https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntutrusty-apache I got an

> Your connection is not secure

error. I´ve tested the SSL Connection with https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html and got an "DNS CAA" warning. After I found out that I have to add the verifier to my DNS (*xyz.com 3600 0 issue "letsencrypt.org"*) the warning disappeared, but I still get the error.

I´ve checked the page with https://www.whynopadlock.com as well, and the only warning I get is

> You currently have TLSv1 enabled.
>   This version of TLS is being phased out. This warning won't break your padlock, however if you run an eCommerce site, PCI requirements state that TLSv1 must be disabled by June 30, 2018.

but the warning states that this should not break my padlock.

I thought that smth. might be cached at the DNS (if this is even possible), but I dont know for certainty. I´ve tested the page on multiple devices and all of them get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve found the problem.
The "www" is somehow missing when I browse the page, so the cert. is registered the the page with "www" in front of it. I´ve created another cert with the missing "www" and now it works